# assign a list of colour to the geom_text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

plot with assigned colors.

```
#color generatering
map2col<-function(x,pal,limits=NULL){
    if(is.null(limits)) limits=range(x)
        pal[findInterval(x,seq(limits[1],limits[2],length.out=length(pal)+1), all.inside=TRUE)]
    }
tmpC <- map2col(mtcars$cyl, c("red", "blue", "yellow"))
#plot 
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_text(aes(colour=tmpC))
```

Question: The color assigned by tmpC does not work. How to make the col as tmpC assigned? Thank you.

Comment: Use `scale_color_manual`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this minor change to the geom_text call:

```
#plot 
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_text(colour=tmpC)
```

[image]

**Edit:**   *Explanation:* in your call to geom_text you assign the color inside an aesthetic, for which there is no associated dataframe; geom_text will look in the mtcars dataframe for the column tmpC, which doesn't exist there.  In the modified call in this answer, the colour is assigned outside the aes, in similar fashion to naming the colour directly e.g.

```
p + geom_text(colour=rep(c('red','purple'), length.out = nrow(mtcars)))
```

*Note:* ggplot2 doesn't throw an error with the colour assignment inside the aes, it just ignores the values that don't match anything in the dataframe.

Comment: Could you make a simple explanation about this? Thank you.